# Is there a way to read a text file and save it in a dynamical char array in C, try it befor and get 'malloc(): memory Corruption'

Tags: c, memory, char, malloc, corruption

I am programming a C program which should read Textfiles which have different size and save it into `char *sending_data`. After that it should copy the content of `char *sending_data` into `char *data` and print me the size of the `*data`.

I already have code to read the File and save it into `char *sending_data`. If I try to copy the content to another `char *`, I get `malloc(): memory corruption error.`

And if I try to print the size of `sending_data` or `data`, I get the `Memory access error.`

```
char * readFile(char *path) {
    FILE *fp;
    char *data = NULL;

    if ((fp = fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Fehler!! / Datei konnte nicht gelesen werrden \n\n");
        return data;
    } else if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        long size = ftell(fp);
        if (size > 0 && (data = (char *) malloc(size + 1)) != NULL) {
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
            if (fread(data, 1, size, fp) != (size_t) size) {
                free(data);
                data = NULL;
            } else {
                data[size] = '\0';
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return data;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /*uint8_t */unsigned char *data;

    int USER_SIZE = 8; // you can also use a macro

    unsigned char *data;


    char *sending_data;
    sending_data =(char*)malloc ( USER_SIZE* sizeof (char));

    sending_data =readFile("../PayloadFiles/ToDo.txt");

    printf(sending_data);
    printf(strlen(sending_data));

    data = (char*)malloc( USER_SIZE * sizeof(char));

    if(data)
        strcpy((char*)data, sending_data);

    printf(data_size);
    printf(data); 
}
```

I expect the content and the size of the file, actually the copied content of the file in an other `char *`

Comment: You are allocating `sending_data` and overwriting it right in the next line.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I removed `malloc` from `sending_data` and i could not print the size of `sending_data`.

Comment: Why do you copy the complete read file into a memory location of size `USER_SIZE` (8) bytes? Are you sure that your file isn't longer?

Comment: Did you try running your program in a debugger? Then you would see the place where it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `printf` correctly.

```
printf(sending_data);
printf(strlen(sending_data));
...
printf(data_size);
printf(data);
```

The first parameter to `printf` is a format string that contains text as well as format specifiers stating how to print additional arguments.  You can get away with this with `sending_data` and `data` if there are no format specifiers embedded in them, but you have a type mismatch when passing in `strlen(sending_data)` and `data_size`.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case causes a crash.

Use a format string to dictate how to print the arguments:

```
char *sending_data;
// no need to malloc since you already did that in readFile
sending_data =readFile("../PayloadFiles/ToDo.txt");

printf("%s\n", sending_data);
printf("%zu\n", strlen(sending_data));

int data_size = strlen(sending_data));
data = malloc( data_size + 1);

if(data)
    strcpy((char*)data, sending_data);

printf("%d\n", data_size);
printf("%s\n", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate enough space in the `data` variable.

```
data = (char*)malloc(strlen(sending_data)+1);
```

It is also good idea to check that `sending_data` is not null after call to `readFile`.

You should probably remove call to `sending_data = (char*)malloc(USER...)` in your main function before call to `readFile` as it will result memory leak (you allocate memory inside `readFile` and overwrite `sending_data` with its result value).

Also, it would be great to call `free` for allocated memory at end if main function (as it good practice to free what you allocated)